# Sending Email from Shared Mailbox (O365) using Python

Tags: python, smtplib

I have tried authentication using username and password of the primary account and sender email of the shared mailbox using smtplib python package, but got:

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def send_email(username, password, sender, receiver, subject, body):
    message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    message["Subject"] = subject
    message["From"] = sender
    message["To"] = receiver
    message.attach(MIMEText(body, "html"))
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587) as server:  
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message.as_string())
    return 'email sent to {}'.format(receiver)
```

```
ERROR_MSG: SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [PN1PR0101CA0041.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')
```

Please extend your expertise on how to send email using Shared Mailbox using smtplib in python.

Comment: attach your code, without it it's very hard to say something.